# Add standard captcha to registration page

Tags: php, captcha

I want to add the standard captcha from Magento to our customer registration page. Now I saw that you can enable this captcha in the configuration (System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> CAPTCHA -> Enable Captcha on Front-end). But when I do that and I go to the registration page, there is still no captcha. But when I click on the registration button I get the message:

Incorrect CAPTCHA.

Is there somewhere a tutorial or something? Because I only found it for the contact page and nothing for the registration page.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Free one  https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 3):

After you configure form for registration the default registration form will be updated with new fields. The preview for the form will be disabled and `"Web-form is not available for direct access."` will be shown instead - it is done to prevent non-registration submissions.

> Configuration parameters
>
> Enable
>
> Enables customization of the default registration form.
>
> Registration web-form

Choose web-form to append to default registration form.

With

> "Displaying Mode" set to "Always"

it is showing fine.

Comment: @TBIInfotech I cant understand what configuration you have mentioned above? Can you please elaborate? I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, probably you need to go to the system-->configuration-->Advanced 
and then enable the the Mage_Captcha.
I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

New registration CAPTCHA's are in a slightly different area. Go to:

Settings > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration:

Turn on: Enable CAPTCHA on Frontend
then sort out the configuration to suit your needs i.e. characters used and if case-sensitive etc